# On my app I want to add a swipe delete option to each list item like on Pandora... How? :/

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

I basically have a list of items, and when I swipe left I want to reveal a delete button on each item.  And when I click..... Whalah!  It deletes!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this plugin: [swipeButton](https://github.com/commadelimited/jquery.swipeButton.js) (blogpost with comments: [swipeButton jQuery Mobile plugin launches](http://andymatthews.net/read/2012/02/19/swipeButton-jQuery-Mobile-plugin-launches.-Millions-rejoice!))

Comment: Thanks man.  I'm trying the demo http://andymatthews.net/code/swipebutton/ but it's not working on my laptop or phone.  I think it's exactly what I want tho...

Comment: Nevermind.  I see it now.  I just got to tie the click functionality to a left swipe within each li, I suppose.  Thanks again